# Relationship between the twistor spaces of Penrose and Salamon

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

In Penrose's construction of the twistor space of Minkowski spacetime $\mathbb R^{1,3}$, we first complexify $\mathbb R^{1,3}$ to $\mathbb C^4$ and then think of points in it as matrices acting on $\mathbb C^2$, which can be depicted as a graph in $\mathbb C^2\oplus \mathbb C^2$, which Penrose calls the twistor space. It makes sense to quotient out by a $\mathbb C^*$ action, following which we get the projective twistor space. In particular, points in the complexified Minkowski space correspond to embeddings of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ into the projective twistor space.

Salamon, on the other hand, defines the twistor space of a general (possibly Ricci flat) quaternionic (pseudo-)Kähler manifold $M$ as the bundle of almost complex structures in the quaternionic subbundle of endomorphisms. The fibre over a point is a sphere which may be identified with $\mathbb {CP}^1$. So there is a $\mathbb{CP}^1$ for every point in $M$.

But then, in Penrose's construction, these spheres are supposed to intersect whenever two points in Minkowski spacetime are null-seperated, whereas in Salamon's consruction, the spheres are all separate fibres over the points of $M$.

So my question is that when we take $M$ to be just the Minkowski spacetime are these two constructions really the same under some identification? If so, what is that identification, and if not, what is the relationship between them?